# ./gradlew connectedCheck works on emulator but not working on real device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing

I have written a demo application which includes unit, instrument and automation testing in android. I am able to successfully test, generate test report using gradle. Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/EspressoDemo).

**./gradlew connectedCheck**  works perfectly fine in Emulator but when i try to run the same test in android real devices i get **connectedAndroidTestDebug FAILED**

[image]

It's quite strange same test runs perfectly fine on Emulator.

Before the start of test when i run **adb devices**, i get the list of connected devices but right just the test finishes adb could not list the connected devices and i get the error as shown in stack trace above.

Anyone facing similar issue? Please suggest if there is any work around or i am missing anything here.

NOTE: Device driver, everything is installed i am able to  run app, install APK on device, also as mentioned in android official documentation for android test support library, devices is running API 18.

Comment: Apparently i found out that the problem was which the cable that i was using to connect device and Macbook. Sorry guys it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your app.gradle file

```
 project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
       connectedAndroidTestDebug {
          ignoreFailures = true
       }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't made any difference, i am still getting the same problem.

Comment: I found out that after changing the cable it worked, thanks for help. It was complete waste of time :)